# Right way to manage nested data

Tags: java, android, json

I'm making a Shopping app which gets product attributes from the server. The Json Array I get from the server contains nested Json objects and Json arrays which look likes this:

```
[
    "id": 1860,
    "name": "T-Shirt",
  
   "attributes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "color",
            "position": 0,
            "visible": true,
            "variation": false,
            "options": [
                "blue",
                "green",
                "red"
            ]
        },
        
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "size",
            "position": 3,
            "visible": true,
            "variation": false,
            "options": [
                "L",
                "M",
                "XL",
                "XXL"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

I created a class for managing product variables which contains of strings and ints and setters and getters for simple variable types like name,price etc.

```
public class Product {
//a class holding product objects for managing through app

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

private String productName;
private String productPrice;
private String oldPrice;
private int attrCount;
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> attrs;



private String description;
private boolean isLoading = false;
private boolean isNew = false;


public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

private String imageUrl="";

public Product( String productName, String productPrice, boolean isNew,String imageUrl) {
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
    this.isNew = isNew;
    this.imageUrl=imageUrl;
}

public Product() {
}
public boolean isNew() {
    return isNew;
}


public void setProductPrice(String productPrice) {
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
}
public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}
```

But for managing attributes I need a  way to bind each attribute name with its options to keep track of them in future.
Because the attributes and options coming from the server are varied each time I can't use something like enums.
I tried to store the data using HashMap<String,ArrayList> in my products class which takes the attribute as a key and option arrays as values.

```
 HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>attrs=new HashMap<>();
             
                for (int j=0;j<attrJsonArray.length();j++){
                   JSONArray optionJsonArray=new JSONArray(attrJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("options"));
                   ArrayList<String>attrsOptionArray= new ArrayList<>();
                   for(int k=0;k<optionJsonArray.length();k++){
                       attrsOptionArray.add(optionJsonArray.getString(k));
                   }
                   attrs.put(attrJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("name"),attrsOptionArray);

                }
```

but it seems like a bad practice. I wonder what is the right way to store this kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse json to java class.

1.Use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` for parsing json.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Product product = objectMapper.readValue(dataOfJson, Product.class);
```

2.Make java class for json.

- Key of json is field name or  name of @JsonProperty.
- Array of json is List or array.
- If exist The deeper field like "attributes",Use nested static class.

```
class Product {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String productName;
    private String id;
    ... other field

    private List<Attributes> attributes;
    
    
    
    // set and get method

    static class Attributes{
        private String id;
        private List<String> options;
        ... other field
        
        
        //set and get method
        
    }

}
```

If you want to try testing, Use this. But I changed a little your json because Your json is not completed.

```
public class JsonToPojo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        String dataOfJson = " {\r\n"
                + " \"id\": 1860,\r\n"
                + " \"name\": \"T-Shirt\",\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + " \"attributes\": [{\r\n"
                + "         \"id\": 1,\r\n"
                + "         \"name\": \"color\",\r\n"
                + "         \"position\": 0,\r\n"
                + "         \"visible\": true,\r\n"
                + "         \"variation\": false,\r\n"
                + "         \"options\": [\r\n"
                + "             \"blue\",\r\n"
                + "             \"green\",\r\n"
                + "             \"red\"\r\n"
                + "         ]\r\n"
                + "     },\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "     {\r\n"
                + "         \"id\": 2,\r\n"
                + "         \"name\": \"size\",\r\n"
                + "         \"position\": 3,\r\n"
                + "         \"visible\": true,\r\n"
                + "         \"variation\": false,\r\n"
                + "         \"options\": [\r\n"
                + "             \"L\",\r\n"
                + "             \"M\",\r\n"
                + "             \"XL\",\r\n"
                + "             \"XXL\"\r\n"
                + "         ]\r\n"
                + "     }\r\n"
                + " ]\r\n"
                + "}";
        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Product product = objectMapper.readValue(dataOfJson, Product.class);
        System.out.println(product);
    }
}

class Product {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String productName;
    private String id;

    private List<Attributes> attributes;
    
    
    
    static class Attributes{
        private String id;
        private String name;
        private int position;
        private boolean visible;
        private boolean variation;
        private List<String> options;
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public int getPosition() {
            return position;
        }
        public void setPosition(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }
        public boolean isVisible() {
            return visible;
        }
        public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
            this.visible = visible;
        }
        public boolean isVariation() {
            return variation;
        }
        public void setVariation(boolean variation) {
            this.variation = variation;
        }
        public List<String> getOptions() {
            return options;
        }
        public void setOptions(List<String> options) {
            this.options = options;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Attributes [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", position=" + position + ", visible=" + visible
                    + ", variation=" + variation + ", options=" + options + "]";
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    



    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }






    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }






    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }






    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }






    public List<Attributes> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }






    public void setAttributes(List<Attributes> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }






    @Override
    public String toString() { // for printing output
        return "Product [productName=" + productName + ", id=" + id + ", attributes=" + attributes + "]";
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I also tried using static class but it didn't feel right neither. The problem is I want my product object to handle  the attribute variables not instantiate another static method

Comment: @HamedHeidari Do you mean contents of attribute variables may be changed? ex) contents of attribute variables may be String, List<String>, Integer etc..